# How do I list all stores, categories and products in OpenCart?

Tags: mysql, sql, report, opencart

I want to list a complete report of my inventory in OpenCart.

It should give me all stores that I have set up, all categories, and all products in one language. I have registered 24 products, but the following query shows 22 rows.

What am I missing? Please suggest.

```
SELECT
    s.store_id,
    s.name store_name,
    s.url store_url,
    c.category_id,
    cd.name category_name,
    cd.description category_description,
    p.product_id,
    pd.name product_name,
    pd.description product_description,
    p.price,
    p.minimum,
    p.image
FROM oc_store s
INNER JOIN oc_category_to_store c2s ON c2s.store_id = s.store_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON p2s.store_id = s.store_id
INNER JOIN oc_category_description cd ON
    cd.category_id = c2s.category_id
INNER JOIN oc_category c ON c.category_id = c2s.category_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_to_category p2c ON
    p2c.category_id = c.category_id
    AND p2c.category_id = cd.category_id
    AND c.category_id = cd.category_id
INNER JOIN oc_product_description pd ON pd.product_id = p2c.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_product p ON p.product_id = pd.product_id
INNER JOIN oc_language l ON
    l.language_id = pd.language_id
    AND l.language_id = cd.language_id
WHERE
    s.store_id = 4
    AND l.language_id = 1
    AND cd.language_id = 1
    AND c.status = 1
    AND p.status = 1
    AND p.date_available < NOW()
GROUP BY p.product_id
ORDER BY
    s.name,
    cd.name,
    pd.name
;
```

The SQL here is for external shell scripting language eg, python, and not for any modifications in OpenCart/PHP itself.

Helpful tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `oc_store` (
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ssl` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`store_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_category_to_store` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`store_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_product_to_store` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`store_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_category_description` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `top` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `column` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_product_to_category` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`category_id`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_product_description` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `tag` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_keyword` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`,`language_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_product` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `model` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `ean` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  `jan` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `mpn` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `stock_status_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shipping` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `price` decimal(15,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0000,
  `points` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `tax_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_available` date NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `weight_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `length` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `width` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `height` decimal(15,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00000000,
  `length_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `subtract` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `minimum` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `viewed` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `oc_language` (
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `locale` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `directory` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`language_id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
);
```

Comment: with a query that is this complex it will be virtually impossible to troubleshoot this without knowing the data that is in your tables. If you can I'd suggest mocking your tables up in either sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) or db fiddle (https://www.db-fiddle.com/) and posting the link here so we can easily take a look at it. If you can't do that, what I would do is start with your product table and re-build your query step by step, adding each table in one at a time to see what part of the query is making it so you aren't getting the results you want.

Comment: I have updated the question with list of helpful tables.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4571ce/2/0 for SQL Fiddle

Comment: can you also provide some sample data in your tables, what your current result set comes back as and what you want your result set to come back as?

Comment: One of the reason I found is some products did not have their categories assigned.

Comment: It seems like you want LEFT JOIN in this instance